# Java to C# translation

Tags: java, c#

When I run the following code in Java, I get the output: `[B@1ddcac5`

**Java Code**

```
byte[] byteA = "test".getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(String.valueOf(byteA));
```

If I try to run the similar code in C#, I just get: `System.Byte[]`

**C# Code**

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
```

How can I get the same output in C# as I do in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Neither output is meaningful if you're interested in the contents of the array.  The Java output is simply telling you the object is a byte array (`'[B'`) and that the array's identity hash code is `0x1ddcac5`.

Comment: Why the hell does this community love to downvote questions that don't meet their level of expertise and superiority. It starts to get old when I come on here looking for help and people downvote or close questions simply because it's not advanced enough. I got many great answers and I thank you guys for that but it really kills the motivation to ask for help when people downvote me every time. I'm just trying to learn and while it may be a stupid question to you, many people had perfectly legitimate answers.

Comment: Why do you want a C# program to produce output that's just as meaningless as the Java one?  It seems like a very strange requirement.

Comment: Your title is vague, and you don't explain what you're trying to do. This question could be improved quite a bit without raising the "level of expertise". And FYI I didn't downvote, because it's not *that* bad.

Comment: The downvote button is labelled "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Well, I don't see any evidence of research effort.  The question is not unclear, although the motivation for the question is completely hidden.  I really fail to see how the question can possibly be useful.  It seems to me like a good candidate for a downvote.  If you want to avoid downvotes, do some research before you post.  And obviously, questions that are likely to be useful to other people will fare better than questions that it's hard to see the usefulness of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same output. Only java prints objects default with both its type and memory address. While in C#, only the type is printed.

The output `[B@1ddcac5`, has nothing to do with its content, the `[B` specifies that the object is an array of bytes (thus equivalent to `System.Byte[]`) and Java also prints the identity hash, which in this case is `1ddcac5` (it is determined by where the object is stored, so if you run your program a second time, the hash will change).  You *could* instead simply print:

```
Console.WriteLine("[B@1ddcac5");
```

But of course the semantics are not the same.

Comment: That line makes perfect sense. I think you mean sensible. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You should fix your Java program first:

```
byte[] byteA = "test".getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteA));
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/8O8tEo)

Now print your array in C# - and the two outputs start matching each other:

```
byte[] byteA = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
for (int i = 0 ; i != byteA.Length ; i++) {
    Console.Write("{0} ", byteA[i]);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/pyYK02)

Answer (score 4):

You can't because **[B@1ddcac5** is the class **instance** identifier created by Java (something like memory address). If you run your code multiple times the output should change.